# Mean squared error between white noise and colored noise

Tags: noise, estimation, white-noise

While studying the whitening filter, I still can't come up with an intuitive and reasonable explanation of why a whitening filter is needed.

As [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/41171/whitened-matched-filter) question and its answer mentioned, I understand that a whitening filter 'decorrelates' the colored noise samples. However, I don't understand why we would like to 'decorrelate' the colored noise samples. What is the advantage of uncorrelated noise? is there any clear advantage in terms of mean squared error?

Let's assume that I have a vector of random variable $X$, and $Y=HX+N$ is a linear estimate of X with some error $N$. Assuming the error sequence $N$ is independent on $X$, but it can be colored or white Gaussian with identical variance and mean. The cost function of this linear estimator is $E=Y-X=(H-I)X+N$.

In this situation, can we still say the white error sequence will still provide lower MSE than the colored error sequence? If so, how can we show this?

Edited: The origin of this question is because of [this paper](https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/274/401/partial_response_decision_feedback_equalization.pdf). This is FFE (feed-forward filter) + DFE system optimized/adapted via MMSE-DFE scheme, which is the core theme of this paper. Here, one can see that the FFE is adapted via MMSE-DFE and therefore, its output error sequence shall be whitened sequence for optimal performance. Assuming the FFE and DFE can equalize ISI perfectly, the noise will be the only error source in this system. My question is: why is whitened sequence a necessary condition? Why not a colored sequence with the same variance?

Comment: You're missing one important thing: "error rate" is something that only a system with some decision can have. You don't describe a receiver, so what you describe actually has no need for a whitening filter. So, write down for which system you think a whitening filter is necessary or advantageous - and then we can discuss that! There is no *general* need for whitening.

Comment: okay, let me change my question to "MSE" instead of error rate.

Comment: Then the answer becomes that the whitening filter has no positive effect, as said above.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've read this article (https://static.aminer.org/pdf/PDF/000/274/401/partial_response_decision_feedback_equalization.pdf), and there is a section explaining that having a white error sequence yields optimal results. Could you elaborate why you said whitening filter has no positive effect?

Comment: Because what you describe above is not a decision feedback equalizer. I don't need to explain that there's no magic effect.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've edited question. please see the original post. My original question is indeed from this paper: I have FFE + DFE, and FFE is adapted via MMSE-DFE. For minimal MSE, the paper suggests that the error sequence b/w EQ output and input must be white. Assuming all the ISI can be cancelled via FFE and DFE, then the only error source is the noise at the output of FFE. In this case, why white error sequence is necessary for optimal performance? why not non-white error sequence with the same variance?

Comment: if you make that assumption, that under both situations equalization was perfect, then the result has the same variance indeed. The point is that the equalization is not perfect if the noise isn't white.

Comment: @MarcusMüller could you elaborate on this portion? when you say it is not perfect, in what sense is it not perfect?

Comment: If your noise is colored, your MMSE estimate is worse than for white noise of the same variance. Hence, your assumption that in both cases the equalization is perfect is wrong; that assumption simply cannot be true for an equalizer in noise. And thus, by making the assumption, any statement that you infer on the noise after equalization is unlikely to be true. So, you'll have to look at the actual equalization performance if you want to evaluate equalization under different noises – really no way around that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I really appreciate your answer, but could you also provide mathematical reasoning why this is true? possibly by answering this question in a formal way instead of comments. I also do have a strong 'feeling' that your comment is right, but I am having a bit hard time proving this mathematically...

Comment: Counterquestion: can you prove your equalization is perfect under noise? That's your claim on which you base your problem. So, please formally prove that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller one possible answer I came up is that MLE and MMSE provide identical estimator for the equalizers under white noise. However, this does not tell me if 'MSE' is lower than what the estimator + colored noise can provide. What other approach would you take ?

Comment: As I tried to gently hint at: I would derive the equalization error under different noise colors.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've found this paper (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/230462) but the conclusion of this paper is that estimator + colored noise may or may not provide higher MSE than white noise (no solid conclusion), and I don't see any problem with this approach (equation 22). As this paper mentions, at the end it depends on the noise covariance matrix... this is where I am stuck right now.

Comment: @MarcusMüller there are few other approaches I've thought: colored noise cannot guarantee sufficient statistic. Assuming the equalizer perfectly cancels ISI, still the final symbol-by-symbol detector may need extra information if noise is colored. but This still does not answer my question in 'MSE' perspective and it is not rigorous enough...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have some extra thoughts and please confirm if you can find any logical loophole in the followings: speaking of sufficient statistics, I think colored noise cannot provide sufficient statistics because the system cannot be modeled as a first-order Markov chain with colored noise. In addition, there is already a nice proof existing saying that sufficient statistics is always optimal detection if the signal is measurable with respect to sigma-algebra (which is always true in digital communication). Thus, colored noise cannot provide an optimal detection rule.

Comment: That is a quite excellent line of reasoning! I like it and support it 100%!